# Cant Install PCLStorage using nuget

Tags: c#, nuget, portable-class-library

I have create a new Protable Class Library Project. I want it to have some IO functionality so I decided to use [PCLStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCLStorage/1.0.1)

So In the Package Manager, I execute this command: `Install-Package PCLStorage` but it fails to install the package. I am given the following error:

> Could not install package 'PCLStorage 1.0.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a  project that targets
>   'portable-net40+sl50+wp80+win', but the package does  not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

**Any pointers to help me out?**

---

Full Error:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'PCLStorage 1.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net40+sl50+wp80+win', but the package does 
not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package PCLStorage -Version 1.0.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [nuspec file](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage/blob/master/common/PCLStorage.nuspec) indicates that the following portable library frameworks are supported:

```
portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+monoandroid+monotouch+Xamarin.iOS+Xamarin.Mac
```

You should try upgrading .NET 4.0 to 4.5 and removing Silverlight from your PCL, as they are obviously not supported by this framework.

Comment: @Krimson Great! I'm pleased I could help.